# Is there a formula to replace a string of numbers with another string of numbers in excel?

Tags: excel, exception, excel-formula

So I track time spent on a client with two different programs. One program uses old billing code another new billing codes. I have a list of the old billing code with their now new codes.

Is there a way I can make a table where I can input the old code which is provided by the client and it replaces it with the new code?

I have 225 pages of billing codes old to new and wish to automate this process.

Example of codes:

```
Prior Code   
00000-101
00000-104
00000-107
00000-112
00000-300
00000-310
00000-312
00000-313
00000-499
00000-491

New Code
100005
100006
100007
100008
100009
100010
100002
311001
311001
311001
```

Comment: 1) Create a 2-Column Table, one column shows the **old codes** and the other shows the **corresponding new codes**. 2) in the table where you want to input the old code to get the new code, create a new column and use `VLOOKUP` to look for the new code from the 2-Column Table created in Step 1.

Comment: That you, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

As you do have that many codes, maybe it could be better to use a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) or [MATCH-INDEX](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match) to look for the matching codes.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to build a "converter" with the vlookup function.
I used this formula:

> =VLOOKUP(A3,A6:B36,2,FALSE)

- **A3** : The input value that you want to convert.
- **A6:B36** : The range of your data that you want to base the research.
- **2** : The column that you expect the result from your range.
- **False** : Matching mode (False = exact match)

[image]